# Web.config - Can I URL Rewrite all HTTP to HTTPS except all ASMX files?

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config, url-rewrite-module

I have Windows hosting with Host Gator. When I enable SSL via their Plesk platform, I assume it writes a bunch of rules including: redirecting all HTTP to HTTPS

I have some legacy ASMX web services which still need to be accessed on HTTP, so I want any attempt to access those via HTTP to remain on HTTP, until I have the chance to roll out new changes (My web services have their own Web.config files in sub-dirs from the main website)

I have added the following into the Web.config for the ASMX service, but i'm experiencing problems. It gets caught in an endless redirect loop!

```
        <rule name="MakeAMSXHTTPOnly" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{R:1}" pattern="^(.*)\.asmx$" />
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
              </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
        </rule>
```

**Should be HTTP:**
http://www.homepage.com/services/service.asmx

**Should be HTTP:**
http://www.homepage.com/service.asmx

**Should be HTTPS:**
http://www.homepage.com

**Should be HTTPS:**
http://www.homepage.com/stuff/morestuff.htm

Comment: I have also tried with <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />, no joy

Answer (score 0):

To allow accessing the webservice using "http" I set a rewrite rule on my site (homepage.com) to redirect to "https" only when not "asmx":

```
<rule name="WebSite HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="\.asmx.*" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```